# Uploading a directory using sftp with Maven

Tags: maven, tycho

How can I upload a directory - Eclipse update site - using sftp with public key authentication in Maven?

For background information: I'm using tycho to build an Eclipse plugin and want to get the update site ( `<packaging>eclipse-update-site</packaging>`) uploaded.

---

[Asked on the Tycho users list as well](http://n2.nabble.com/Recommended-way-of-deploying-update-sites-td4086622.html#a4086622).

Comment: Do you mean during `deploy` or something else?

Comment: Not sure if deploy would work - I'm using tycho to build an Eclipse plugin and want to get the update site uploaded.

Answer (score 10):

I don't get why you couldn't use `mvn deploy` to deploy your `eclipse-update-site` artifact. So, this is my suggestion.

First, update your `distributionManagement` section:

```
<!-- Enabling the use of FTP -->
<distributionManagement>
  <repository>
    <id>update-site</id>
    <url>sftp://your/url</url>
  </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Then, add the wagon extension for sftp:

```
<build>
  <extensions>
    <extension>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
       <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
       <version>1.0-beta-6</version>
    </extension>
  </extensions>
</build>
```

Finally, add the credentials into your `~/.m2/settings.xml`:

```
<server>
  <id>update-site</id>
  <username>foo</username>
  <password>secret</password>
</server>
```

And run `mvn deploy`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When deploying with Tycho I get the following results: all plugins are deployed as plain maven artifacts, with addition p2artifacts.xml and p2metadata.xml files and the update site is deployed as a jar containing the site.xml file.

Comment: Hmmm... Actually, I'm not sure to get your comment. On top of that, I wonder if https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/TYCHO-258 is a blocking issue...

Comment: Trying to do this, I get `Permission denied (publickey,password).`, can someone help?

Answer (score 5):

Like above's answer but instead of wagon-ssh-external one needs to use wagon-ssh otherwise you'll get an error saying that sftp URLs are not known.

Comment: Answers shouldn't reference other answers. Instead, either propose an edit to the other answer, or provide a new standalone answer by copying the relevant parts from other answers.